# Transformation of function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Say for a function $f(x)$;[image]

Now if we have a transformation of lets say $f(2x)$ what we are doing is replacing every original $x$ value with a value $2$ times of it in the equation. So essentially if $x=2$ the new $x $value inputted would be $x=4.$

What about when x is negative? Well $x=-2$ then the new $x$ input is $x=-4.$ However would this still result in a horizontal compression for the graph in question? For the bottom bit, near the point of inflection (the RHS of it), to undergo a compression the x value would have to be replaced by something positive would it not? e.g. $x=-1.$ If we were to replace that with $x=-2$ then it would give it the same value?

Can somebody please explain where I am going wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a very detailed answer prepared, but it seems to have gotten a little technical and I don't think it is any more illuminating. If you wish me to edit this response and post it, just ask.

The short version requires you first only consider positive integers $n$. When you make a substitution like $x\rightarrow nx$ it is like you are standing at the origin and pulling everything in. If you compare the original polynomial to the substituted one, and picture yourself on a stroll from the origin out along the x-axis, this substitution means you hit the same y-value sooner on the substituted polynomial than your original. Where you used to have to walk all the way to 10 to get at some value of the polynomial, now you only have to walk to 5.

Because you are only pulling on the x-axis, no y-values change. Because you are pulling on *both sides* of the x-axis, all features are pulled proportionally to the origin but not crossing it.

If you switch $n$ to a fraction instead of an integer, your pull becomes a push. If you change the sign, you mirror everything about the y-axis and then pull/push.

Comment: Thats great thanks. Would you mind answering another question on the same topic?

Comment: If I can answer I will try.